# How to delete a property from an object copy?

Tags: typescript

If for example I have an object that looks like this:

```
const rabbit = {
  color: 'blue',
  personalData: {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 35
  }
}
```

and I make a copy of it using the spread operator and then try to delete a field:

```
const rabbitCopy = {
  ...rabbit
}
delete rabbitCopy.personalData.name
```

How can I avoid the message: `"The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional."`
I understand why this message appears as for typescript it doesn't make sense to let the user delete a property as it would break the contract... but in my case, I need to do it

How can I at the moment of copying the object, define the copy with optional components?

The only way I've seen to handle this scenario is the following but I don't quite understand what is happening:

```
delete (rabbitCopy.personalData as unknown as Record<string, unknown>).name
```

Answer (score 0):

[Typescript infers the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) of `rabbit`, since it has no explicit type:

[image]

You can tell Typescript that `name` is an optional property like this:

```
type Rabbit = {
  color: string;
  personalData: {
    name?: string;
    age: number;
  }
}

const rabbit: Rabbit = {
  color: 'blue',
  personalData: {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 35
  }
}
```

And then this will not cause any errors:

```
const rabbitCopy = {
  ...rabbit
}
delete rabbitCopy.personalData.name
```

[Try it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgIwQS2FAvFA3gKClAYwHsAbIgJwC4oBnYc5AOwHM8pJyajG4SAROMDjVc+fDwC2EAPzU6DFgG42+OMwjVGAVwkII5ZfgC+OEzmKM6UcohTBq8JKgzY2xMlSgByBCS0QvABo2Di4efkFhVzEoSQ1vACEiBCCVKDV4gGYAVjYTMwsrGydgAGEiMBAXUSgAOnriu1McABMIEghgaEbUcsra0O5eASFauJwgA)

Answer (score 0):

Create name field optional inside type and copy,

NOTE: When you delete it'll delete from rabbit object also, destructuring only creates a shallow copy.

```
type Rabbit = {
  color: string
  personalData: {
    name?: string;
    age: number;
  }
}

const rabbit:Rabbit = {
  color: 'blue',
  personalData: {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 35
  }
}

const { name, ...personalData} = rabbit.personalData;
const copy = {
    ...rabbit,
    personalData
}
```